# apache cxf Endpoint getInInterceptors() is not returning anything nor the getTypeClass of MessagePartInfo in jdk17

Tags: soap, wsdl, cxf, java-17

cxf version is 4.0.3
openjdk17

The below snippet is not returning any interceptors

```
Endpoint endpoint = client.getEndpoint();
List interceptors = endpoint.getInInterceptors();
```

Though the other APIs like endpoint.getEndpointInfo().getAddress() & endpoint.getService() are returning values.

The below snippet is also not returning getTypeClass()

```
List<MessagePartInfo> parts = inputMessageInfo.getMessageParts();
for(MessagePartInfo part:parts) {
        MessagePartInfo partInfo = part;
        Class<?> partClass = partInfo.getTypeClass();
        if(partClass!=null)
                logger.debug("partClass ==>"+partClass.getCanonicalName());
        }
```

The same code used to work in jdk8 and cxf 3.1.18
I am trying to upgrade the cxf version.